# Symfony - Accessing Service from Custom Class

Tags: symfony, logging, service, doctrine, monolog

I am trying to log information with Monolog library from a Custom Class that I have created that is called Common.

I have included logger as an argument in service.yml for that class

```
parameters:
services:
   appbundle.helper.common:
   class: AppBundle\Helpers\Common
   arguments: ['@doctrine','@logger']
```

I have also initialized the Logger Interface for that class.

```
    private $dataEntityManager;
    private $suppEntityManager;
    private $curation;
    private $innerDoctrine;
    private $logger;

    /**
     * Common constructor.
     * @param ManagerRegistry $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->dataEntityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $this->suppEntityManager = $doctrine->getManager('gtsupp');
        $this->curation = new Curation($doctrine);
        $this->innerDoctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function detail($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f = "", $g = true, $h = true)
    {

       $this->logger->error('Type not supplied in Common detail ' . __LINE__ . " for descriptor: " . $b);

     }
```

The problem is that each time I want to use class::Common **I have to provide the logger** in Class's constructor.

```
    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="homepage")
         */
        public function indexAction(Request $request)
        {
            $common = new Common($this->getDoctrine(), $this->get('logger'));
            $common->detail('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

            return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
                'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/..') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

P.S.
Same problem occurs with doctrine. I have to pass it every time I call Common class as you can see above.

Comment: Pulling it from the container as the answer below suggests is the legacy way.  If you happen to be using S3.3+ then try public function indexAction(Request $request, Common $common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$common = new Common($this->getDoctrine(), $this->get('logger'));
```

to this:

```
$common = this->get('appbundle.helper.common');
```

In your way your are not using dependency injection, in the good way you don't need to pass all parameters to instantiate your service

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please provide me with the documentation alongside this? I never found it.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html @marioskamperis glad to help you!